# Run time error 1004 method range of object_global failed on a search in Excel with a named range

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting error:

> Run time error 1004 method range of object_global failed

in the following code line:

`Set br = Range("rg").Find(Range("$d$3").Value)`

Following is the complete code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim y As String
Dim q As Variant
Dim j As Double
Dim i As Variant
Dim k As Variant
Dim l As Double
Dim qst As Variant
Dim br As Range
Dim bra As Variant

qst = MsgBox("Entire data will be removed & archived" & vbNewLine & "Are you sure you want to proceed?", vbYesNo, fnb)
If qst = vbYes Then
Worksheets("Marcopolo").Unprotect myp
Worksheets("Marcopolo").Activate

Dim arch_iv(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant

Dim rg As Variant
Dim fd As Variant

For rg = 1 To 5
    For fd = 1 To 2
        arch_iv(rg, fd) = Worksheets("arrays").Cells(rg, fd).Value
    Next fd
Next rg


For rg = 1 To 5
    For fd = 1 To 2
        Set br = Range("rg").Find(Range("$d$3").Value)
            br.Select
                br.Offset(0, 2).Select
                  bra = ActiveCell.Address
                MsgBox bra
            Range("fd").Copy
        Worksheets("marcopolo").Range(bra).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next fd
Next rg

Else
GoTo Gtout
End If
```

Comment: rg and fd refers to defined ranges in sheet "Marcopolo"

Comment: Does your range **rg** contain value that is in your cell d3 ?

Comment: I'd guess your code is not in the Marcopolo sheet module. Use `Application.Range("rg")` and not just `Range("rg")`

Comment: rg and fd refers to defined ranges in sheet "Marcopolo"... rg has been assigned with ranges mentioned in worksheet "Arrays"

Comment: This code runs from the userform.combobox

Comment: D3 is a cell in Marcopolo holding name of the month to match with.

Comment: Clearly you do *not* have ranges actually named "rg" and "fd" or your code would work. I suggest you clarify your question.

Comment: Actually the question is clear enough - the error is because the "rg" is not a named range in Excel. If there is a need to refer to range from `Array()` in Excel, then this would better be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes, because the named range is not found.
If the named range `rg` should be on the "Marcopolo" worksheet, then it should be referred like this:

```
With Worksheets("Marcopolo")
    Set br = .Range("rg").Find(Range("D3"))
    If br Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "D3 NOT FOUND!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
end with
```

The above has another problem, because the parent of the `Range("D3")` is not explicitly defined. Thus, it is either the `ActiveSheet` or the Worksheet, in which the code is residing. To avoid this problem, consider defining it like this `Worksheets("SomeName").Range("D3")`.

Comment: rg is an array holding 5 ranges mentioned in worksheet "Arrays" but these ranges exist in sheet Marcopolo. If you may notice Marcopolo is the active sheet therefore Range(d3) should not be the problem

Comment: @Kal - So, `rg` is an array, defined in VBA with the loop in your code? This is why it throws an error, the `.Range("Something")` expects a named range or Excel range. Not arrays.

Comment: What i mean is that rg is the first dimension in the array arch_iv                          
 and rg holds 5 ranges

Comment: @Kal - This means exactly, that you cannot use it like this. You have to pass a string to `Range()` and this string should mean something to Excel. The first dimension of an array does not mean anything to Excel. Thus, `Range("rg")` is an error.